# How can I find where actually is the theme file?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to Symfony and I need to work to a large project with many themes to modify them. How can I find where actually is the theme file in which module, just looking at the HTML browser output? Or do I need to look somewhere else, routing for example?

Comment: A bit more information about what you're doing with these themes and how they're used by the app would be helpful. As a starting point, I wouldn't start dividing them into lots of modules but think of one central place to keep them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use the [Web Debug Toolbar](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/16-Application-Management-Tools#chapter_16_sub_web_debug_toolbar).

Once you have that running on the page, using appname_dev.php, simple click the view link and it will show you which templates have been used. If you need to know which layout to use then use logs link, click none the sfPHPView.